# Чем отличается от других коллекций HashSet и для каких целей она используется?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Если не ошибаюсь, то некоторые другие стандартные коллекции имеют(или может быть достигнуто) схожее поведение и более того другие коллекции могут иметь больше кол-во возможностей, чем HashSet.

В чем собственно изюминка HashSet и для каких задач он предназначен?

Comment: Зачем вы лепите тэги windows и microsoft ко всем вопросам?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HashSet` в отличии от обычных коллекций хранит в себе уникальные значения. Это хэш-таблица (как `Dictionary<K, V>`), в который ключи одновременно являются и значениями. Уникальность определяется с помощью хэшкода значений и проверки их на равенство. Поэтому если вы будете использовать `HashSet` для своих типов, в них нужно корректно переопределить `Equals()` и `GetHashCode()`.

[Пример](http://ideone.com/7z2EEO):

```
var set = new HashSet<int>();

Console.WriteLine(set.Add(42) ? "Added" : "Not added");
Console.WriteLine(set.Count);

// повторим
Console.WriteLine(set.Add(42) ? "Added" : "Not added");
Console.WriteLine(set.Count);
```

Распространенные сценарии использования `HashSet`:

- выделение уникальных элементов из существующей коллекции (см. [перегрузку конструктора](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb301504(v=vs.110).aspx))
- поиск за О(1) (например, если вам нужно сформировать коллекцию, а затем многократно по ней искать, лучше сразу использовать `HashSet`)